# On Serre's problem regarding the injectivity of Albert-Algebra cohomological invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

In these Lecture Notes http://molle.fernuni-hagen.de/~loos/jordan/archive/cohinv/cohinv.pdf from 2006 by Garibaldi on page 21. 7.5 there is the following open problem mentioned:

Is the map

$g_3 \times f_3 \times f_5: H^1(-,F_4) \rightarrow H^3(-,\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) \times H^3(-,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \times H^5(-,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$

injective?

It was orginally brought up by Serre in Cohomologie galoisienne.

Has this been answered by now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the lecture notes [Albert algebras](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/11-12/exceptional/Alb.-alg.-Ottawa-2012-Vii-new.pdf) by H.P. Petersson, written in $2012$ this is still mentioned as an open problem, see Question $13.2$: 
Is an Albert algebra $J$ determined up to isomorphism by its invariants $g_3(J),\, f_3(J),\, f_5(J)$ ? This is equivalent to the injectivity of the map given above. 
Peterson writes that "a complete answer to Question $13.2$ is fairly well out of reach at the moment".